# How to render an image on cairo::Context in gtk-rs

Tags: gtk, rust

I'm trying to render an image (gif/png) on a `DrawingArea` in gtk-rs. I can read the image file with `Pixbuf`:

```
Pixbuf::new_from_file("/path/to/img.gif")
```

But I cannot find a way to render the `Pixbuf` into `cairo::Context`. I noticed that `gdk::prelude::ContextExt` has `set_source_pixbuf()`:

https://docs.rs/crate/gdk/0.1.4/source/src/cairo_interaction.rs

So I tried to use this:

```
extern crate gdk;
use gdk::prelude::*;
```

...

```
drawingArea.connect_draw(move |widget, context| {
    context.set_source_pixbuf(&ws.pix, 0f64, 0f64);
    context.stroke();
    return Inhibit(false);
});
```

But nothing is rendered. The `ContextExt` seems unimplemented (it seems to specify null to the second parameter of `gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf`)?

```
fn set_source_pixbuf(&self, pixbuf: &Pixbuf, x: f64, y: f64) {
    unsafe {
        ffi::gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(self.to_glib_none().0, pixbuf.to_glib_none().0, x, y);
    }
}
```

Is there any other method to render an image on `DrawingArea`?

Comment: remark: The `.0` syntax is used to access the first field of a [tuple struct](http://rustbyexample.com/custom_types/structs.html). It does not pass `null` there. In this case it uses [glib::translate::Stash](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/glib/translate/struct.Stash.html).

Comment: Thanks, I found solution.

Answer (score 2):

I need to use `Context.paint()` instead of `Context.stroke()`:

```
context.set_source_pixbuf(&ws.pix, 0f64, 0f64);
context.paint();  // need to call paint() instead of stroke().
return Inhibit(false);
```